# Xamarin Android: The AVD Manager visual interface is not available for your version of sdk tools 26.1.1. Please use the sdk manager to downgrade

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

When I try to open the Android Emulator Manager in Visual Studio, a message is shown with the error: "The AVD Manager visual interface is not available for your version of sdk tools 26.1.1. Please use the sdk manager to downgrade to sdk tools vs25.x".

I already used the sdk manager to download sdk tools version 25. However somehow, Visual Studio is still seeing the 26.1.1 version.

How I workaround this? Considering that I cannot uninstall sdk tools 26.1.1 as it is needed in React Native development?

Thank you

Comment: https://javiersuarezruiz.wordpress.com/tag/xamarin-android-device-manager/

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is by installing [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html), set the path of the SDK in Android Studio's SDK manager to that of Visual Studio's and then use the AVD manager in Android Studio.